# Why is positioning a shape not precise?

Tags: excel, vba, position

I cannot position a shape precisely at the left corner of a specific cell. The further away the column the worse it gets, Column FP is more off then column A.

I am using Excel 2016.

Here a very simple code that demonstrates my problem.

```
Sub test()

Dim x As Double

Dim y As Double

x = Range("z1").Left

Selection.ShapeRange.Left = x

y = Selection.ShapeRange.Left

End Sub
```

Value for the variable are x= 596.25 and y=596.549.

Values for x and y should be equal since I forced the shape left corner to the x value. Why is it not?

Code and variables value
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and let me know how it goes! This will only work for shapes that you have selected, let me know if you need to move specific shapes by referencing their names.

```
Sub test()
Dim x As Double
Dim y As Double

x = Range("Z1").Left
y = Range("Z1").Top
With Selection.ShapeRange
    .Left = x
    .Top = y
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: My code was working, the problem is that it does not position the shape where it should be. I forced the shape left corner to be aligned with the cell Z1 but it is somewhat off. It get worst the further away you are from the first column.

Comment: Weird, I tested it with different positions and different cells and this put it in the right spot every time. Do you have any other code running on the sheet?  Do you have a lot of cells hidden or anything like that too?

Comment: Following your comment, I try the same macro on an empty sheet and it works fine. The only thing different in the sheet I had problem is that their is several merged cells but no hidden columns. The lines I was reffering was empty with no merged cells. It is very strange.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the specific cell with:

```
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(4)
    .Left = Range("L22").Left
    .Top = Range("L22").Top
End With
```

You will need to figure out which Shape # you're working with (example uses 4)

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to pinpoint the problem starting at column C. After numerous tests without success, I finally changed the column B width by a small increment and the problem was solved.

I don't know why, maybe a glitch in Excel.

Thank you to everbody who tried to help me.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for sharing your findings! I'm sure you just saved Future me a headache lol.